# Why is many to many visible in a Link To Entities Query until I project it out to a SelectItemList?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have this query.

```
   IQueryable<Staff> aolStaff =
            _userRepo.Users
            .Include(u => u.StaffOffices).ThenInclude(so => so.Office)
            .Include(u => u.Positions).ThenInclude(p => p.Role)
            .Where(u => u.Positions.Any(p => p.Role.RoleCd == "PO_ALO"));
```

UsersRepo here returns an IQueryable of Staff objects.

A Staff object has a list of StaffOffices and Postions.  These are both Entity Framework Core 2 many to many bridge tables.

A StaffOffice Object has a StaffId and an OfficeId and a navigation property to a 
a Staff object and an Office object.

A Postion Object has a StaffId and a RoleId and a navigation property to a 
a Staff object and a Role object.

Here is the StaffOffice POCO:

```
[Table("staff_office")]
public class StaffOffice
{
    [Column("staff_office_staff_id")]
    public short ID { get; set; }
    public Staff Staff { get; set; }

    [Column("staff_office_office_id")]
    public short OfficeID { get; set; }
    public Office Office { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the Position POCO:

```
[Table("position")]
public class Position
{
    [Column("position_staff_id")]
    public short ID { get; set; }
    public Staff Staff { get; set; }

    [Column("position_role_id")]
    public short RoleID { get; set; }
    public Role Role { get; set; }
}
```

When I run this query I am able to set a break point and see the results.
The Staff in the results has a StaffOffice collection and the Office is there and I am able to get to the office name.

But I need to project this out to a SelectItemList.

So I try to change the type of the query result from IQueryable of Staff to IQueryable of SelectListItem and tack this on to the end of the query.

```
.Select(u =>
                new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = $"{u.FullName}" + $"{u.StaffOffices[0].Office.OfficeNm}",
                    Value = u.StaffID.ToString()
                });
```

What I really need the Text of each SelectListItem to be is Full Name and a comma delimeted list of offices like this:

Sam Miller (OFCO, PGA, OLM)

So here is the whole query:

```
IQueryable<SelectListItem> aolStaff =
            _userRepo.Users
            .Include(u => u.StaffOffices).ThenInclude(so => so.Office)
            .Include(u => u.Positions).ThenInclude(p => p.Role)
            .Where(u => u.Positions.Any(p => p.Role.RoleCd == "PO_ALO"))
            .Select(u =>
                new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = $"{u.FullName}" + $"{u.StaffOffices[0].Office.OfficeNm}",
                    Value = u.StaffID.ToString()
                });
```

Eventually I need the format I wrote above for the text but at this point I am simply trying to get the first Office Name in the first element of the StaffOffice Collection's Office's OfficeName.

But I get this exception when I hit the breakpoint and expand the results:
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I know this isn't much to go on but I've been looking at this all day and I just don't know what to do.

If I run this I get an Office Name for every Staff Member in the query:

```
foreach(Staff staff in aolStaff)
        {
            string nm = staff.StaffOffices[0].Office.OfficeNm;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("nm: " + nm + "\n");
        }
```

How Can I get this query to the next step?
What am I doing wrong.

Why is no matter how I try to get these results into a SelectListItem it seems to think something (I think the StaffOffice collection) is null?

---

**UPDATE**

Thanks  Mickaël Derriey.

Fist() gets me an office in the results:

[image]

This is the query now

```
IQueryable<SelectListItem> aolStaff =
            _userRepo.Users
            .Include(u => u.StaffOffices).ThenInclude(so => so.Office)
            .Include(u => u.Positions).ThenInclude(p => p.Role)
            .Where(u => u.Positions.Any(p => p.Role.RoleCd == "PO_ALO"))
            .Select(u =>
                new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = $"{u.FullName}" + $"{u.StaffOffices.FirstOrDefault().Office.OfficeNm}",
                    Value = u.StaffID.ToString()
                });
```

Now I need to take this part:

```
$"{u.StaffOffices.FirstOrDefault().Office.OfficeNm}"
```

and do something like:

```
$"({u.StaffOffices.Join(','))"
```

to make the comma delimited list.
Further more it would be nice to not show an empty () if StaffOffices count is 0.

---

**UPDATE 3**

Nope - I take it back. It's not working.  It's only showing full name text.  Not the office info.  So FirstOrDefault() is returning null.

Going to try making the QueryResult IQueryable and the forloop it into IQueryable

Comment: If the query where you retrieve `Staff` instances works but the one where you project to `SelectListItem` doesn't, I think it means that EF Core doesn't support (doesn't know how to translate to SQL) something you use in the `Select` method. Could you try replacing `u.StaffOffices[0]` with `u.StaffOffices.First()`?

Comment: Thanks I'll try first. Interestingly, when I put u.StaffOffices.Count() I get "Sam Miller (2)" format for all of my Staff Users.
i might just loop through the IQueryable with a separate for and fill a SeletListItem list.  Hate to do that - but deadlines.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it was working.  I just didn't see an office like OM to the right of full name because I forgot a space in between.

Here is the final code:

```
IQueryable<Staff> aolStaffMembers =
            _userRepo.Users
            .Include(u => u.StaffOffices).ThenInclude(so => so.Office)
            .Include(u => u.Positions).ThenInclude(p => p.Role)
            .Where(u => u.Positions.Any(p => p.Role.RoleCd == "PO_ALO"));

        List<SelectListItem> aolStaffList = new List<SelectListItem>();
        foreach (Staff staff in aolStaffMembers)
        {
            aolStaffList.Add(
                new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = $"{staff.FullName}" + $" ({string.Join(", ", from o in staff.StaffOffices select o.Office.OfficeOrganizationCd)})",
                    Value = staff.StaffID.ToString()
                }
            );
        }
```

This is what I needed to get the comma delimeted list:

```
string.Join(", ", from o in staff.StaffOffices select o.Office.OfficeOrganizationCd)})"
```

I would still like a check if StaffOffices.Count() == 0 then don't show offices or empty ().